# Where to store business data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, design-patterns, architecture

I have a Rails app using MongoDB. I'll expose one single case although there are many others that would fit.

I've got a User model. Some User fields:

```
:first_name
:last_name
:email
:password_hash
:avatar
:roles
```

Sometimes it is interesting for us to know some data about how users interact with our app. For example, we want to know how many visits each user gets. What I thought about is to make a POST from client. Every time a user visits someone's profile a field inside that profile's owner (User) would be incremented.

Therefore, we can run reports based on that "stats".

One of my team-mates argues that that isn't a good practice as we'd end up with lots of requests all over the app. How people usually do this? Is it a good practice to make POST requests via AJAX and store it in database?

Answer (score 0):

If someone's profile access need a connection, you can add a record in your database with the `current_user` (the visitor) when the `show` action of the controller (the action displaying the profile view) is called, and you'll know who's visiting each profile.

Else, just add a `view_count` column in your `User` model and, when the `show` action is called, increment this column.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approachs to any problem, and also it depends of requirements.

For example, when are these reports requested? Do you need them on demand or you plan to run them once a day? In the latter, you can create a cron task or similar to generate reports in low activity times (night?).

If you need them on demand, you can try to cache some data to reduce server load.

But the thing is, if you need to store stats, data, you need to hit the database anyway. Make this hits quick and light (send only id and generate the rest of the info server side).

If you don't want to end up filling your users table with stat-related fields, you can create associated tables with that info, related to the user with the id. But again, you want stats? You need to store them somewhere.